# Call a controller action from ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Hey I have an ajax call which currently calls a php file with queries inside it. I am moving it to controllers and models. How can I call a controller action using ajax.
My Ajax call is

```
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/logs/opening_log.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false
            });
```

What should I put in url if I have to call the box_openings_log action of openings_log controller.

Thanks

Comment: Just `openings_log/box_openings_log`, Controller name without .php `/` and the action name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/index.php/openings_log/box_openings_log",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false
});
```

Comment: try `/index.php/openings_log/box_openings_log`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/openings_log/box_openings_log",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false
});
```